# Comparar elementos de dos columnas

Tags: r, bucle-for, bucles, comparaciones

Tengo un dataframe que es mas o menos así:

```
df1 <- data.frame(ID = c("ES5163", "ES5167", "ES5168", "ES900", "ES300", "ES5255"),
                  Padre = c("ES1820", "ES2223", "ES3858", "ES5163", "ES5168", "ES2222")
```

Quiero un script que identifique cuáles elementos de la columna ID aparecen también en la columna Padre. Cuando aparezca el ID en padre, quiero que en Padre sea == "000000", de tal modo que el resultado final sea:

```
df2 <- data.frame(ID = c("ES5163", "ES5167", "ES5168", "ES900", "ES300", "ES5255"),
                  Padre = c("ES1820", "ES2222", "ES3858", "000000", "000000", "ES2222")
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Con R base.

```
df1[df1$Padre %in% df1$ID,"Padre"] <- "000000"

      ID  Padre
1 ES5163 ES1820
2 ES5167 ES2223
3 ES5168 ES3858
4  ES900 000000
5  ES300 000000
6 ES5255 ES2222
```

Con `df1$Padre %in% df1$ID` obtenemos un vector de lógicos dónde TRUE son las filas dónde el `Padre` apareció en `ID`.

Comment: Mil gracias. Pensé que debía recurrir a un bucle, pero desde luego esta respuesta es muchísimo más sencilla y efectiva